# Convert TS interface to type by refactoring

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems VSCode doesn't support converting TS `interface` to `type` refactoring action.

As you can see, there is no "convert to type" option.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That refactoring does not appear to be part of the stock visual studio code refactorings. They are listed here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-refactoring#:~:text=To%20see%20the%20available%20TypeScript,Ctrl%2BShift%2BR%20directly. you will probably need to install another extension for TS refactoring if you want additional features.

Comment: Are you using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)? Otherwise, I can't really see what would be so hard about just doing ti by hand.